# Weird error when getting posts from Firebase - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a weird error that I do not know how to solve, let me explain:

(I should say there is more code before the following, if you want to see)

```
for i in 0..<self.followings.count {

                    let following = self.followings[i]
                    print("\(following.Id) and \(self.followings.count)")

                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").queryOrderedByChild("profilePhoto").queryEqualToValue(following.Id).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

                        var newUpdates = [Sweet]()


                        for update in snapshot.children {
                            let updateObject = Sweet(snapshot: update as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                            newUpdates.append(updateObject)

                        }

                        self.updates = newUpdates.reverse()
                        print(self.updates.count)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                    }) { (error: NSError) in
                        print(error.description)
                    }



                }
```

This is my code for showing posts from users that `currentUser` is following, in my feed (`UITableView`). The problem is when someone is clicking the like button, the person which post was liked will double every time currentUser clicks like.

I can prevent that from happening if I mode this line of code: `var newUpdates = [Sweet]()` up before `viewDidLoad`. But if I do so then the feed will only show posts from one of the users that currentUser is following - even if I am following two users or more.

So how can I show all posts from users I am following and NOT duplicate when clicking like on one of their posts? Let me know if you need more code :-)